# TypeScript "Go to implementation" in VS

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, typescript, web-essentials

Is there a shortcut in Visual studio for Typescript to go to the implementation of an interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can right click 'Go to implementation' on the interface member and it will take you to the class member implementation.

Answer (score 2):

No. But you can do "find all references" using <kbd>Ctrl + K + R</kbd>.

FYI, since interfaces aren't there at runtime I see little motivation for doing the traditional Implementation vs. Interface programming. It might be relevant in your use case though.